# Is a website for "exchanging" fan-fiction works legal?

Tags: copyright, internet

I want to make a website where fan-fiction writers will write a story based on a prompt given by another, and said "another" will in exchange write a story based on *their* prompt.

In other words, a person can ask for a story they want to read and in exchange write a desired story for another. Story exchange, if you will.

I know fan-fiction technically isn't legal, although I don't know if that's when it's made commercially or just for fun. Would it be legal for the site to essentially encourage fan-fiction works?

I'm not looking to make any money here, though it would be nice if I could ask for (very) small donations to cover server costs and such. Is either case legal?

Comment: You're describing a club, where members congregate voluntarily (and might pay a fee towards maintenance of the clubhouse), write stories based on one another's ideas, and exchange the stories they write. Why do you think this might be illegal?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Well, you could have a club where you, say, help out and encourage internet piracy. Would that be legal? -- that was my thought process, anyway. If it's fine, then great!

Comment: Depends what the club and the members do. To the extent your club promotes or fosters internet piracy, club users would be vulnerable to charges of conspiracy to commit whatever piracy it is. To the extent people write and exchange alternate endings to public-domain fairy tales or their own fan fiction, they're not.